# Backpropagation matrix multiply error Andrew Ng Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation

In the Backpropagation algorithm video(Gradient Computation, week 5), he has taken an example neural network of 4 layers.(Input, 2 Hidden, Output).

So, I had made my own example, I have taken

```
x = [3x1] Matrix (Vector)
y = [4x1] Matrix (Vector)
Theta = [6x4, 6x7, 4x7] Matrices respectively(with weights added).
```

Theta was taken according to s(j+1) x s(j) + 1 Rule.

Then calculating deltas,

```
delta_4 = a^(4) - y => 4 x 1
delta_3 = theta[3]'(7x4) X delta_4(1x4) *g'(z(3)) => 7x1
delta_2 = theta[2]'(7x6) X delta_3(7x1) * g'(z(2)) = error
```

The problem I am facing is `theta[2] is a 6x7 Matrix`. Its transpose is a `7x6 Matrix`. We can multiply a matrix when the `A(c) = B(r)`, where c and r are columns and rows respectively. So Taking a transpose doesn't allow me to multiply the matrices.

[image: Example Neural Network]
`theta2 is a 6x7 matrix and delta3 is a 7x1 matrix(vector)`

`theta2_transpose is a 7x6 matrix` which doesn't allow me to multiply. So Please tell me where I'm getting it wrong. can anyone one of you can explain in `matrix(r, c) format`? Need answers, Please.

Comment: Add a link to the lecture video?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvAEX5taVKk

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference This link explains how to use math typesetting.

Answer (score -1):

Since your y matrix is 4x1, your delta4 matrix should also be 4x1. This allows the multiplication

```
delta_3 = theta[3]'**(7x4)** X delta_4**(4x1)** *g'(z(3)) => 7x1
```

Alternatively,

```
delta_3 = theta[3]'**(4x7)** X delta_4**(1x4)** *g'(z(3)) => 7x1
```

As for delta_2,

```
delta_2 = theta[2]'(6x7) X delta_3(7x1) * g'(z(2)) = error
```

Alternatively,

```
delta_2 = theta[2]'(7x6) X delta_3(1x7) * g'(z(2)) = error
```

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference This link explains how to use math typesetting